# index was out of range in combo box item clear method

Tags: c#-4.0, combobox

My combo box lists the record from database. my combo box is as :

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Name="comboBoxEmp" SelectionChanged="comboBoxAdministrator_SelectionChanged" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFF90C0C" />
```

I have method to fill combo box as :

```
 void FillComboEmpName()
        {

            MySqlConnection conn4;
            conn4 = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=root;database=newcompanydatabase;pwd=Admin@123;");
            string Query = "select * from nWorksUser";
            MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn4);
            try
            {
                conn4.Open();
                MySqlDataReader rdr;

                rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    string EmpNo = rdr.GetInt32("uid").ToString();
                    string fname = rdr.GetString("fname");
                    string lname = rdr.GetString("lname");
                    comboBoxEmp.Items.Add(EmpNo + "-" + fname + " " + lname);
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex1.Message);
            }

        }
```

As i use the following method to reset the content of combo box i got error :
"index was out of range. must be non negative or less than the size of collection. parameter name : index"

```
public Reset()
{
 comboBoxEmp.Items.Clear();
 FillComboEmpName();
}
```

Comment: have you run in debug and put a break point on the names and numbers. One reason can be it's pulling a null value.

Comment: No. Actually I am not familiar to that process. but in fact if combo box elements are already null and then we fire comboBoxEmp.Items.Clear(); then its ok it fires that exception. but it showing error for every instance.